# CustomPaint drawLine cannot apply transparency on lines drawn

Tags: flutter, dart, custom-painting

I was trying to use alpha channel to apply transparency on line colors with `CustomPaint`'s `Canvas.drawLine()`.

### Problem

However, the color tweaks on alpha channel takes no effect on the results, for example, the following code still gives me 100% opaque white lines

```dart
  final gridPaint = Paint()
    ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.miter
    ..strokeWidth = 1.0
    ..color = const Color(0xe6ffffff)
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;


  canvas.drawLine(start, end, gridPaint);
```

### Workaround

I have to draw 1-pixel-wide `drawRect` to get transparent lines.

### Question

Is this by design?

Comment: Not sure about this but is the result same if you try `fromARGB` like  `Color c = const Color.fromARGB(0xe6, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff);` ?  referred from [Color docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html)

Comment: what are the values for start and end?

Comment: @dev-aentgs Wow. That's a surprise. `Color.fromARGB` works!

Comment: I don't think that fromARGB would change everything, see it's implementation here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/Color.fromARGB.html

Comment: @pskink It actually did. I just tried his suggestion and it works the same way as `withOpacity`

Comment: @pskink as for your start/end question, they are vertical lines from `top=0` to `bottom=size.height`

Comment: are you suggesting that 0xe6ffffff != 0xe6 << 24 | 0xff << 16 | 0xff << 8 | 0xff ? IMHO it would be a big bug it the dart arithmetics

Comment: @pskink Tried your test in DartPad and it's a false. So no bug in arithmetics. It could be a bug in the `Color` or `Paint`, though. For now I have no time digging into this. But might be worth a report to Github later.

Comment: see https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9dgMr28jqb/, green part is done using `drawRect`, red part is done using `drawLine`

Comment: and? does `drawLine` apply transparency (50% in this particular case) on your device?

Comment: so change the path to the folder where you have write access (maybe some `/sdcard/` or something?), i used flutter for desktop so i was able to write it in my current folder, or maybe use https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider: "A Flutter plugin for finding commonly used locations on the filesystem. Supports iOS, Android, Linux and MacOS. Not all methods are supported on all platforms."

Comment: OK, I got it working. Saw in the image written to the card: from the topleft corner a green square with blurry horizontal gradient, from bottomright corner a red one.

Comment: @pskink I've added the code and resulting image to an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63481303/987846. Please feel free to complete it with your arguments. From what I can see the leftmost portion of each square doesn't look like transparent, where you assigned `0x80` as alpha, correct?

Comment: no, its not blurry - you got the exact same image like me (i posted it in base64 format here https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9dgMr28jqb/), open it with https://www.gimp.org/ for example, zoom in and you will see 50% transparency

Comment: @pskink ok, my bad. It's the oversampling of device picture viewer. So the conclusion is that the hex form of the Color value works just fine?

Comment: yes, it works just fine - there is no difference if you use `Color(0x80xxxxxx)` or `withOpacity(0.5)`

Comment: btw, check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c969b8af7b/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/colors.dart#L244 and other `black*` or `white*` colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [withOpacity](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/withOpacity.html) method on the color of your choice.

```
Colors.green.withOpacity(0.5)
```

or

```
Color(0xe6ffffff).withOpacity(0.5)
```

Set the value to a number from 0 to 1 depending on the level of opacity you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

On behalf of @pskink, I'm posting his test code and resulting image from my Android device:

```dart
    print('devicePixelRatio: ' + MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio.toString());
    var pr = ui.PictureRecorder();
    var c = Canvas(pr);
    var p = Paint();
    c.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 1, 3), p..color = Color(0x8000ff00));
    c.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(1.5, 0, 1, 3), p);
    c.drawLine(Offset(3.5, 3.0), Offset(3.5, 6.0), p..color = Color(0x80ff0000));
    c.drawLine(Offset(5.0, 3.0), Offset(5.0, 6.0), p);
    var img = await pr.endRecording().toImage(6, 6);
    var data = await img.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    final imgDir = Platform.isAndroid ?
    (await pathman.getExternalStorageDirectories(type: pathman.StorageDirectory.pictures))[0] :
    (await pathman.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory());
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      await Directory(imgDir.path).create(recursive: true);
    }
    final suffix = DateTime.now().toString().replaceAll(RegExp(r'[\:\ \.]+'), '-');
    final filePath = '${imgDir.path}/screenshot-$suffix.png';
    File(filePath).writeAsBytesSync(data.buffer.asInt8List());
```

Having the above code in my `CustomPaint`'s `paint()` gives me the tiny image below.

[image]